# AttributeError when taking result of counter, but not with a plain integer

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm attempting to use the code below to get the total number of lines in a text file.

```
totallines = 0
for line in infile:
    totallines += 1
```

It works, and can print the correct number to the shell. However, when I assign the result to:

```
item = [0]*totallines
```

I get an AttributeError when forcing the given line into lowercase with:

```
item[i] = item[i].lower()
```

Yet, if I remove the line counter, and replace it with the number of lines in the text file. It works perfectly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If `item=[0]*totallines`, then `item=[0, 0, ..., 0]`, and `item[i] = 0`, so what is `0.lower()` supposed to mean?

Comment: item=[0] * 24 works though, which is what's confusing me.

Comment: Well, why don't you post your exact code, `lower()` is a string method, and only works on strings. Therefore `item` must contain strings rather than integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to convert the lines of the input file to lowercase and store the result in an array.  You could do it this way:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    items = [line.lower() for line in infile]
```

Or (somewhat) equivalently, (This one drops the "\n" at the end of each line):

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    items = infile.read().lower().splitlines()
```

*Note: Don't use `file` as a variable name, since it overshadows the builtin `file` type.*

Comment: @Joel Cornett: People use `file` all the time because it hardly ever needs to be referenced explicitly (so usually hiding it doesn't matter).

Comment: @martineau: Makes sense. I guess in a similar way, I use `string` all the time, because I hardly ever import the `string` module.

Comment: Brian L, it's your question, so your call.

Answer (score 0):

`item = [0]*totallines` will create a list of 0s equal in length to `totallines`.

If you want to copy the file into a list and access a given line (say, the sixth line), this is how you do it:

```
item = []
for line in infile:
    item.append(line)

print(item[5].lower())
```

or, more concisely, using a built-in method of file objects:

```
item = infile.readlines()
print(item[5].lower())
```